# Using IPython magic functions in a module

Tags: import, module, ipython, ipython-magic

Is it possible to write a python module (it will be used exclusively from ipython interpreter) and execute python magic functions?

E.g.

MyModule.ipy

```
def MyFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    #do something useful
    %this_is_a_magic_function_call $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

MainModule.ipy

```
import MyModule

MyModule.MyFunction(1, 2, 3)
```

When I run `ipython MainModule.ipy` it ends with a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
I suppose that the reason is that MyModule.ipy is not a valid python code, but haven't found if and how it is possible to use such modules.

Update: I have found this question ([IPython Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1031659/1010666)), where such practice is discouraged.