# Import functions that use ipython magic

Tags: python, shell, ipython, python-import, ipython-magic

In ipython cells you can execute shell commands as follows:

*ipython:*

```
print("asdf")
!echo asdf
```

However, if you try to import this code from file,

**asdf.py:**

```
def asdf():
  print("asdf")
  !echo asdf
```

*ipython:*

```
from asdf import asdf
```

it results in an error.

```
!echo asdf
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The use case for that is repetative massive scripts in google colab utilizing *ffmpeg*, *wget*, *mount*, e.t.c.
While you can use `os.system` or `subprocess`, they are not as interactive in providing real-time stdout.

Comment: This is an ipython feature. You cannot use the `!` syntax in Python in general.

Comment: And what exactly is your question, actually?

Comment: Imo this might be impossible, since Ipython magic happens only in the interactive shell, before the input is passed to python interpreter. That's not the case with import statements.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I wonder how can I reuse (e.g. by importing) code that uses ipython magic. I prefer to use it because of the fact that os.system and subprocess methods of executing shell commands do not provide interactive/real-time output.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361206/how-to-run-an-ipython-magic-from-a-script-or-timing-a-python-script

Comment: But I don't think that using `subprocess` would be a problem, if done properly.

Comment: @mkrieger1, thank you for the provided link, I did a little bit of research and came up with solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use case solution

If you want to reuse code that has ipython magic functions in it, simply use `%run` instead of the `import`.

*ipython:*

```
%run utils.ipynb
```

**utils.ipynb:**

```
def asdf():
  print("asdf")
  !echo asdf
```

Example above works fine.
Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419367/3565642).

---

### On reusing ipython code

Why the original question was an *A-B problem* of some kind? The reason is that you *should not really drag ipython additional functionality* to the pure python execution.

- If you have a, let's say, *google colab* notebook with useful utils,
  then just `!wget` it from the public link and `%run` it.
- If you have a *python script* to execute, do a regular `import` on `.py` files.

Sure, there are ways to import `.ipynb` files to python code: Jupyter notebook's [Notebook Loader](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html), [ipynb package](https://ipynb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [nbimporter package](https://github.com/grst/nbimporter) (but even the nbimporter's author says *you should not really do that*. Just convert your notebook to `.py` using VSCode or another tool).

So, if you use ipython research environment and features, *just stick with it*. Or switch to pure python environment with proper modules, testing, e.t.c.

---

Also, if you're struggling with doing `wget`:

```
file_id = "1xE8Db1zvQ7v-z13CO2qc3F6wJmtr3YHu" # can be extracted from public link
file_out_name = "utils.ipynb"
!wget "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=""$file_id" -O "$file_out_name"
```

However, on the problem of calling cmd, *I see no way of executing shell commands interactively* in python with one line. While `subprocess` can do that, [it takes multiple lines to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python).